# button или input

Tags: html, submit

Можно ли использовать `<button type="submit"/>` , как `<input type="submit/>`. И какая между ними разница?

Comment: никакой.... причём у button по умолчанию в форме итак тип submit, который можно не писать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`button` по умолчанию имеет `type="submit"`, если находится в теге `form`, разница в том, что `button` можно лучше стилизировать (хочешь картинкой, хочешь фоном и т. д.), ну и у `button`, как нового элемента HTML5, поддержка чуть хуже, хотя сейчас уже не критично .

Comment: Ага, спасибо, парни, работаем

Comment: А можно ли писать JS код в одном файле с Jquery кодом?

Comment: @FeelsBadMan, Wow, а в чём между ними разница?

Comment: ну, синтаксис, например

Comment: @FeelsBadMan синтаксис у них не различаается. Ещё что-нибудь?

Comment: @FeelsBadMan на заметку: JQuery это библиотека на языке JavaScript. Когда вы думаете, что пишете «на JQuery», вы на самом деле пишете на JS.

Comment: `<button>` со всеми его фичами появился ещё в HTML4

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к соседнему ответу:

1. <strike>input элемент по умолчанию имеет `display:inline`, в то время, как `button` - `display:block`</strike> в FF input по умолчанию имеет `display:inline`, в остальных браузерах, значение display совпадает с button: `display:inline-block`
2. Кроме этого, `button` может быть контейнером для других элементов, в отличие от `input`.

```css
span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="submit" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" value="2" />
  <input type="submit" value="3" />
  <input type="submit" value="4" />
</form>

<form>
  <button type="submit"><span>1</span> <span class="green">11</span></button>
  <button type="submit"><span>2</span> <span class="green">22</span></button>
  <button type="submit"><span>3</span> <span class="green">22</span></button>
  <button type="submit"><span>4</span> <span class="green">33</span></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если используется длинное слово или целое предложение на кнопке - лучше использовать `button` вместо `input`, т.к `input` по умолчанию `white-space: nowrap`.

Также `button` поддерживает работу с псевдоэлементами

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

[type="submit"] {
  /*display: block;*/
  padding: 15px 35px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
}

[type="submit"]:before,
[type="submit"]:after {
  content: 'i';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: tomato;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

[type="submit"]:after {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>input type="submit"</h2>
<input type="submit" value="Submit text text tetx text text text tetx text text text tetx text text text tetx text text text tetx text text text tetx text">

<h2>button type="submit"</h2>
<button type="submit">Submit text text tetx text text text tetx text text text tetx text text text tetx text text text tetx text text text tetx text</button>
```

Comment: раз уж ты сделал display:block, у инпута, сделал бы ему еще и `white-space: normal;` тогда бы все переносилось

Comment: @Grundy - для input по умолчанию white-space: nowrap установлено.

Comment: ну у него еще и display другой установлен, но раз уж ты поменял одно css свойство, почему бы сразу не поменять и другое?

Comment: @Grundy поправил, т.е убрал display: block