# Что такое "Обычная кнопка" (button type='button')

Tags: html

Есть кнопки для создания "обычных кнопок"

```html
<input type="button" value="Обычная кнопка" />
<button type="button">Обычная кнопка 2</button>
```

А для чего они используются? Т.е. если кнопки типа reset сбрасывает все данные формы, кнопки типа submit шлют HTTP запрос с данными формы по указанному URL, а что делает "обычная кнопка"?

Можно самый простенький пример?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727902/button-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cамый простенький пример:

```html
<input type="button" value="Обычная кнопка" onclick="test.style.color='red';"/>
<button type="button" onclick="test.style.color='green';">Обычная кнопка 2</button>
<div id="test">TEST</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

button может быть контейнером для других элементов, в отличие от input.

```html
<button type="submit"><span>1</span> <span class="green">1</span></button>

<input type="submit" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

ну например всё что вы укажете в своих javascript сценариях

Например вывод сообщения по клику на кнопку

```
<button type="button" onclick="alert('сообщение');>кнопка </button>
```